# Rails 3 keep a single table the same across all environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some data that needs to be edited online (ie cannot be a seed), but that also needs to be the same in all environments. So far the only thing i found is the [has_alter_ego](https://github.com/aduffeck/has_alter_ego) gem, but it does not seem to be supported anymore.

Example:

> - I make many changes to the default_settings table in my development database
> - I would like to keep **only** these changes transferred from my development to production database (and not the other tables which have test data)
> - I would rather not use a seed unless there is a way to edit seeds from the web

One option that i'm considering is having a separate database.

Anyone have a clean solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You could just update your config/database.yml to have all environments use the same database. I might be over simplifying your problem...

Comment: I need to share a single table not a whole database :)

Comment: found out that on heroku you can to this with heroku db:push --tables logs,tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you define a second sqlite3 database which gets checked in with your app for just this table, and use it for all three environments? For example, the sqlite3 file could be named other_db.sqlite3:

config/database.yml:

```
... (your other settings for dev, test, and prod databases)

other_db:
  database: db/other_db.sqlite3
  adapter: sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

app/models/external.rb:

```
class External < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :other_db  
end
```

app/models/cross_environment_data.rb

```
class CrossEnvironmentData < External
  ...
end
```

Comment: That's what i was thinking of but was wondering if it's the correct/simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (though thoroughly discouraged), I would put it in a migration.

/db/migrate/_edit_data.rb

```
class EditData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    <Do your edits here>
  end

  def self.down
    <undo edits here>
  end
end
```

Then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now you have the same data across all environments.

For example if you wanted to append some text to the end of a chunk of text across all records of a Post.text.

```
script/generate migration append_text
```

/db/migrate/_append_text.rb

```
class AppendText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Post.each{ |p| p.update_attribute(:text, "#{p.text} my additional text")}
  end

  def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

When you run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

on development, the changes will propagate accordingly and when you deploy to your other environments, you will have to run the same command and they will receive the same changes. This is more of an irreversible migration because you won't be able to validate that the data did not change since the time of migration, so make sure this is what you want to do (run it on dev) =)

NEW SOLUTION:

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps

when you want to transfer a list of tables

```
$ taps push postgres://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/dbname http://httpuser:httppassword@example.com:5000 --tables logs,tags
```

Comment: not sure what you mean? How will one change to my development database be propagated to my production database? Unless i'm missing something, this is the same as a seed file. Please let me know if you see something i'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the extra example. It's still not what i am looking for unfortunately. I'll clear up my question a bit (see above).

Comment: Can this data be changed via a CMS on production?

Comment: Yes, but i would need it back in development for my testing :)

Comment: If there is a rake to dump and restore a single table that would work (couldn't find one though)

Comment: How about doing the changes on production, and doing a db:pull from production to overwrite your development environment?

Comment: Acutally i answered that last question too quickly. I cannot make changes directly in production, i need to test the changes first in development.